# Python: Reduce rectangles on images to their border

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, image-processing, rectangles

I have many grayscale input images which contain several rectangles. Some of them overlap and some go over the border of the image. An example image could look like this:

[image]

Now i have to reduce the rectangles to their border. My idea was to make all non-white pixels which are less than `N` (e.g. 3) pixels away from the border or a white pixel (using the Manhatten distance) white. The output should look like this (sorry for the different-sized borders):

[image]

It is not very hard to implement this. Unfortunately the implementation must be fast, because the input may contain extremly many images (e.g. 100'000) and the user has to wait until this step is finished.

I thought about using `fromimage` and do then everything with numpy, but i did not find a good solution.

Maybe someone has an idea or a hint how this problem may be solved very efficient?

Comment: How fast is your current implementation? :)

Comment: I didn't implement it, because i would it do it with loops (similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159345/python-adding-noise-to-images-is-very-slow). But this is incredible slow. Probably even worse with nested loops. In the posted link i required some seconds for ~1'000 images.  This is the reason why i hope there is a good trick / algorithm to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Calculate the distance transform of the image (opencv distanceTrasform http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html)
2. In the resulted image zero all the pixels that have value bigger than 3